# Retrive Param from SQL SERVER Query on PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a really annoying problem with a simple query.

So:

```
INSERT INTO [SapuV2].[dbo].[ALERGIA] ([DESCRIPCION]) OUTPUT INSERTED.PK_ALERGIA VALUES ('test')
```

PK_ALERGIA is a primary identity key, and i need the new id created.

PHP code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ALERGIA (DESCRIPCION) OUTPUT INSERTED.PK_ALERGIA VALUES(?)";
$id = 0;
$params = array(
  array(&$nombre, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$id, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT)
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->Conn, $sql, $params);
if( sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === false){
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}else{
  var_dump($id);
}
```

I'm able to save records on my BD, but $id is always 0 ...

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it, but i'm not proud ...

Using same SQL Query, but change the sqlsrv_execute to a sqlsrv_fetch_array

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ALERGIA ([DESCRIPCION]) OUTPUT INSERTED.PK_ALERGIA VALUES (?)";
$params = array(
  array(&$nombre, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);
$rows = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn, $sql, $params);
if($rows === false){
  die(var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()));
}else{
  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rows, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
INSERT INTO ALERGIA (DESCRIPCION)select @var=scope_identity()
```

Comment: So, 
    INSERT INTO ALERGIA (DESCRIPCION) OUTPUT INSERTED.PK_ALERGIA into @var VALUES(?)

and get 
    [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@var".

Comment: Can you please try this query as there seems to be a problem with the first one: INSERT INTO ALERGIA (DESCRIPCION)select @var=scope_identity()

Comment: Actually, i just want to know why my **SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT** it's not been filled and it's keeps the initial value ...